Failing to clip and export chirps rainfall data as CSV in Google Earth Engine
I wish to export daily rainfal data as CSV in Google Earth Engine for a 40 year period. However the code first fails to clip the data to the study area, and also it fails to export the results as CSV. I am getting the error message that Line 16: precipitation.clip is not a function. The code is as follows :
var zimbabwe = ee.FeatureCollection('users/amazhindu/zimbabwe')
Map.addLayer(zimbabwe)
print(zimbabwe)
print()
Map.centerObject(zimbabwe, 6);
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('1983-01-01', '2023-12-31'))
                  .filterBounds(zimbabwe)
var precipitation = dataset.select('precipitation');
var precipitationVis = {
  min: 1,
  max: 17,
  palette: ['001137', '0aab1e', 'e7eb05', 'ff4a2d', 'e90000'],
};

Map.addLayer(precipitation.clip(zimbabwe), precipitationVis, 'Precipitation');
var final = precipitation.clip(zimbabwe)
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: precipitation,
  description: 'Zimbabwe_Chirps',
  scale: 30,
  region: zimbabwe,
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
});


I have tried the above code but I get the error message Line 16: precipitation.clip is not a function and also it is failing to export. I expect to be able to clip to the ROI which is Zimbabwe and to export the daily data as CSV for the 40 years
